# What is the default conflict strategy for insert queries in SQLite DBMS and Room ORM?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

Actually, I think I have figured out the answer. SQLite fails if I try to break constraints while inserting a row. Room ORM ignores the query in the same scenario. Am i correct with this information?

I don't understand why they both behave so differently. Also, I didn't find it mentioned anywhere in Room's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Insert). The docs tell me that I can pass my own conflict resolution strategy but nowhere specifies the default strategy. Especially when it's different to SQLite dbms strategy. Can anyone help me understand this better?

### Edit 1

Okay, So now I know that Room's insert query has a conflict strategy of **ABORT**. Here is the link to [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Insert.html#onConflict()) where it is mentioned. Also, Sqlite defaults to **ABORT**. However, in Room, *Abort* means the query returns a long value just like a regular insert query. In Sqlite *Abort means* it is going to show a Constraint Error. Still confused about this.

Comment: Room's default conflict strategy is ABORT, as you can see in the documentation for the onConflict() method of INSERT, UPDATE annotations. The default for the ON CONFLICT clause in sqlite is also ABORT https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

Comment: @Luksprog, Thanks for the quick reply. Insert query returns a long value in Room. As far as I know, it would return a positive number for successful queries and -1 if any error occurs. When I was trying it out, it returns positive number even when I try to break Uniqueness constraint.  When i try to do the same thing on SQLite server by typing the query, I get a ConstraintError. I don't understand why it behaves differently in these platforms when they both are set to Abort on conflict.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to post some code in your questions as an example for the entities and dao used in room and the sqlite code you tested against.

Comment: I was about to do that. Here is the github link to all Room related classes in my project. https://github.com/sahilpatel14/AwesomeTodoListApp/tree/v1/app/src/main/java/com/example/awesometodolistapp/data/sources/local/database

Comment: I wrote all my findings from running kinds of queries in a gist. (This was before knowing about default abort strategy) [Here](https://gist.github.com/sahilpatel14/1519c364ab0b516b5a7c42e7a5f301b3) is the link for it.

Comment: Room will fail if you break the constraint when using the default ABORT. Your code, however, isn't using ABORT it uses the REPLACE strategy.

Comment: Damn. I din't notice it at all. Thanks @Luksprog for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Luksprog in comments. The strategy defaults to ABORT in both Room and SQLite DB. Both will throw error when we break any constraint. I was however using a Replace strategy *(I followed some blog or codelab)* and din't notice it. Just a silly mistake from my end.